# Sum of numbers excluding those coming between 5 and 8(5 and 8 inclusive)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

How to find sum of all the numbers in the list `[1,2,2,5,3,1,7,8,4]` that do not lie between `5` and `8` (5 and 8 should also be not considered in the sum) in Python( i.e. sum= 1+2+2+4=9) ?

Comment: Are you excluding those values that are between `5` and `8` numerically, or that are between `5` and `8` *in the list*?

Comment: Obviously, Those are between 5 and 8 in the list

Comment: can you check if my answer solved your problem?

Comment: 1+2+2=5 (exclude that combination) 5+3=8 (exclude that combination) 5+2=7 (exclude that combination ...  is this the pattern your seeking?

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum_of_numbers(input_list):
    output_num = 0

    for a in range(0,len(input_list)):
        position = 0

        for n in input_list:
            if n == 5:
                pos1 = position

            if n == 8:
                pos2 = position
            position+=1

        output_num = output_num + input_list[a]

    for b in range(pos1,pos2+1):
        output_num = output_num - input_list[b]

    return output_num

input_list = [1,2,2,5,3,1,7,8,4]
output_num = sum_of_numbers(input_list)
print(output_num)
```

Comment: I hope it is an irony

Comment: @SergeyShubin, at least it is correct. Most other answers do not give 9 as the OP asks.

Answer (score 1):

Not as cool as [the generator solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53091896/383793), but a lot shorter than the [other correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63243194/383793).

```
l = [1,2,2,5,3,1,7,8,4]
print(sum(l[:l.index(5)] + l[l.index(8) + 1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range(5, 8+1)` to define list of numbers to exclude, and simply loop through your numbers and exclude the range,

```
numbers =  [1,2,2,5,3,1,7,8,4]
exclude = range(5, 8+1)  # exclude numbers 5,6,7,8

# sum numbers excluding numbers between 5-8
print(sum(number for number in numbers if number not in exclude))
# output,
13
```

Answer (score 0):

This generator yields all of the items of the list that do not fall between a `5` and an `8` in the list.  We can then pass that generator to `sum` to get the sum of those values.  It works by taking all of the items that are not `5`, then ignoring all of the items that are not `8`, while also ignoring the first `8` it sees after a `5`

```
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile

def outside(iterable, start, end):
    it = iter(iterable)
    yield from takewhile(start.__ne__, it)
    yield from dropwhile(end.__eq__, dropwhile(end.__ne__, it))

print(sum(outside([1,2,2,5,3,1,7,8,4], 5, 8)))
# 9

print(list(outside([1,2,2,5,3,1,7,8,4], 5, 8)))
# [1, 2, 2, 4]
```

Comment: @Ben Why not? This isn't excluding items based on their value, but on their position in the list (which is what I think the asker wants)

Comment: Gotta love this. :) Generalized to any iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using passing a generator expression to `sum`:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,2,5,3,1,7,8,4]
>>> sum(i for i in lst if not 5 <= i <= 8)
13
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sum = 0
for number in [1,2,2,5,3,1,7,8,4]:
    if not 5 <= number <= 8:
        sum += number
```

Comment: Code only answers are not considered good. An explanation on how your answer works would be good.